# Too many values to unpack with function in python?

Tags: python, list, error-handling

I have text presented as such:

```
text = ["A/abc","B/abd","C/abc","D/xyz"]
```

The output I want is

```
 mylist1 = ["A","C"]
 mylist2 = ["B"]
 mylist3 = ["D"]
```

where the only tags I'm looking for are "/abc" and "/abd"

Right now what I have is:

```
def searchWord(segment):
    word_tag = segment.split('/')

    if re.finditer('ab',word_tag[1]):
        if re.finditer('abc',word_tag[1]):
            letter = word_tag[0]
            mylist1 = letter
        else:
            letter = word_tag[0]
            mylist2 = letter
    else:
        letter = word_tag[0]
        mylist3 = letter

    return mylist1
    return mylist2
    return mylist3

mylist1,mylist2,mylist3 = [searchWord(segment) for segment in text]
```

It seems to work fine, but throws the exceptions:

```
 ValueError: too many values to unpack.
```

My "text" list is fairly large, could this be the issue? I didn't have this issue before building a function for this process.

Thanks!

Comment: Since `text` has 4 items, so will the list comprehension. It's not clear how to use a list comprehension to reduce it to a 3-item list that you can unpack into your three lists. Fixing `searchWord` to return a tuple will not address that problem.

Comment: @chepner could you elaborate? I'm not sure I understand...

Comment: `text` has 4 items, so `searchWord` will be called 4 times, and your list comprehension will also contain 4 items. You can't use a list comprehension to perform the kind of reduction you seem to want (i.e., `[ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ] -> [ ['a', 'b'], 'c', 'd' ]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Problem**

You really should have included the full stack trace, but in this case it was easy to deduce that `mylist1,mylist2,mylist3 = [searchWord(segment) for segment in text]` Is the problematic line, since the list-comprehension returns more than 3 values, you can not assign them to only 3 variables. But the problem in your code is that you are trying to `return` more than once.

```
return mylist1
return mylist2
return mylist3
```

You can only have 1 return for a function, so you should change that to something like:

```
return (mylist1, mylist2, mylist3)
```

---

**A solution**

After looking at your code, and seeing your desire. I fixed it for you:

```
def catagorize(data):
    container = [[],[],[]]
    for segment in data:
        searchWord(segment, container)
    return container

def searchWord(segment, container):
    letter, tag = segment.split('/')
    if tag == 'abc':
        container[0].append(letter)
    elif tag == 'abd':
        container[1].append(letter)
    elif tag == 'xyz':
        container[2].append(letter)
    else:
        raise ValueError('unknown tag')
```

Running the code:

```
>>> text = ["A/abc","B/abd","C/abc","D/xyz"]
>>> mylist1, mylist2, mylist3 = catagorize(text)
>>> print mylist1, mylist2, mylist3 
['A', 'C'] ['B'] ['D']
```

---

**Another Solution**

A much more robust solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def catagorize(data):
    container = defaultdict(list)
    for letter, tag in (segment.split('/') for segment in data):
        container[tag].append(letter)
    return container
```

In action:

```
>>> catagorize(["A/abc","B/abd","C/abc","D/xyz"])
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'xyz': ['D'], 'abc': ['A', 'C'], 'abd': ['B']})
```

Answer (score 5):

Return your lists as a tuple instead:

```
return mylist1, mylist2, mylist3
```

Python does not execute all three `return` statements, only the first.

If you are trying to sort your items into different categories, you'd normally use a dictionary:

```
buckets = {'abc': [], 'abd': [], 'xyz': []}
for segment in text:
    item, tag = segment.split('/', 1)
    buckets[tag].append(item)
```

You can then still extract those three lists into 3 variables, but you may as well reference the buckets directly. Instead of `mylist1`, you'd refer to `buckets['abc']`, for example.

Comment: It should be like `return (mylist1, mylist2, mylist3)` right?

Comment: @KDawG: commas make tuples, not parens.

Comment: @Wooble just tested, looks like they both produce the same result :)

Comment: I think you got it. I'm getting a different error, but I know how to handle this one now. I'm new and not totally familiar with tuples, so I need to read up on those. thanks!

Comment: This does not solve the problem, it is not even the cause of the problem, and it doesn't help the OP get the solution he wanted. Notice, he wants each iteration to append to 3 different lists based on their content... The approach is completely wrong.

Comment: How are you not getting a Error: local variable 'mylist2' referenced before assignment?

Comment: @InbarRose: I was called away in the middle of working on the answer. It was indeed incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Only the first `return` is executed. `return` returns an answer **and** it returns the control to the caller. Any returns after that are never run.

So you don't return three items as you expect, but only the contents of mylist (which is apparently not a three-item list).

What you want:

```
return (mylist1, mylist2, mylist3)
```